# Determining a fling from a pan in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, gestures, pan, onfling

I'm developing a game with LibGDX and I'm having trouble determining a `fling` from a `pan`.

My `GestureListener`:

```
@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    //if (velocityX > 1000f) {
    // I can use this to exclude slow pans from the executing a fling
        System.out.println("Flinged - velocityX: " + velocityX + ", button: " + button);
    //}
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    // but there doesn't seem to be a way to have this not fire on a fling
    System.out.println("Panned - deltaX: " + deltaX);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    System.out.println("Pan Stop - pointer: " + pointer + ", button: " + button);
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that if both `pan` and `fling` fire. I understand that a `fling` is basically a fast `pan`, but I need to be able to determine between the two gestures so I can handle each one separately.

A succinct way of asking is, how do I provide unique actions for `fling` and `pan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reasonable solution for this in my opinion is to use `longPress` to set some *boolean* flag to 'enter the panning mode' when swiping without long press will only be about making fling.

This is how I see this:

```
    //the flag for checking if pan mode entered
    boolean PAN = false;

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        PAN = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        if(!PAN) {
            System.out.println("Flinged - velocityX: " + velocityX + ", button: " + button);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        if(PAN) {
            System.out.println("Panned - deltaX: " + deltaX);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        if(PAN) {
            PAN = false;
            System.out.println("Pan Stop - pointer: " + pointer + ", button: " + button); 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Of course if the `longPress` is too long for your purposes you can change it by using `setLongPressSeconds(float longPressSeconds)` method of the [GestureDetector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.html) instance

Comment: This technically works, but seems impossible to get the "feel" right. I am able to detect between pan and fling, however I've been playing around with the long press duration for a while now and it seems nearly impossible to get a good number for this to work. ~100ms (0.1s) seemed to work the best for me while testing on my Nexus 5, but it wasn't consistent. Sometimes what felt like a pan to me (slower than a swipe/fling) didn't register and sometimes it did.